# Как заставить Visual Studio Code выделять PHP-переменные вместе с "$"?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Увы, моя рабочая машина на столько слабая, что проект в PHP Storm уже тупо зависает а после крашится. Visual Studio Code подходит для работы, но этот недостаток с переменными убивает все плюсы редактора.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В settings.json нужно добавить:

```
"editor.wordSeparators": "`~!@#%^&*()-=+[{]}\\|;:'\",.<>/?"
```

Вместо оригинальной строки:

```
"editor.wordSeparators": "`~!@#$%^&*()-=+[{]}\\|;:'\",.<>/?",
```

Comment: не подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать если у меня setting.json выглядит так: 

{
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "files.autoSaveDelay": 2000,
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false
}

Comment: @Леха попробуй просто добавить приведенную в выше строку в settings.json. Вполне вероятно, что это не поможет, т.к. прошло 4 года, но попробовать стоит.

Comment: это же наоборот разделители, там же наоборот нужно из строки убрать знак доллара

Answer (score -2):

> Как заставить Visual Studio Code выделять PHP-переменные вместе с “$”?

VSC умеет это из коробки. Во всяком случае такая:

```
Версия 1.6.1
Фиксация 9e4e44c19e393803e2b05fe2323cf4ed7e36880e
Дата 2016-10-13T15:43:46.054Z
Оболочка 1.3.7
Обработчик 52.0.2743.82
Node 6.5.0
```

Может просто у вас тема такая выставлена, которая символ `$` расцвечивает отдельно. Например, вот Solarized Light:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот Light+:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Просто подбирайте тему, которая вас устроит, в тамошнем marketplace их столько, что устанешь выбирать.