# Как сделать чтобы Visual Studio Code выделял PHP-переменные вместе с "$"?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Всем привет!
Как заставить Visual Studio Code выделять PHP-переменные вместе с “$”?

```
Мой VS CODE:
Version: 1.74.2 (user setup)
Commit: e8a3071ea4344d9d48ef8a4df2c097372b0c5161
Date: 2022-12-20T10:29:14.590Z
Electron: 19.1.8
Chromium: 102.0.5005.167
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.15-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19043
Sandboxed: No
```

[Вот здесь описано решение проблемы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/585752/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-visual-studio-code-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-php-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81) но я не могу найти settings.json (Просканировал весь диск C:)
Может есть какое-то другое решение?
Или в какой папке лежит settings.json ?
Мой VS code установлен в C:\Users\plavv\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\
Может нужно что-то в реестре подшаманить?

Comment: Нужно просто зайти в наcтройки VSCode и в поиск ввести `wordSeparators`

Comment: Супер спасибо! помогло! Поставил wordSeparators  `~!@#%^&*()-=+[{]}\|;:'",.<>/?